# Bootstrap3: how to set 2 html div side by side in the header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this should be a basic problem to solve.  I'm just trying to get 2 div side by side in my header.

I'm using bootstrap 3. I'm also using this template https://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

Here is my html-css code.

```
  <div class="masthead">
    <!-- That's what I tried. Help me to find the good css style please -->
    <div class="pull-left" style="display:inline-block; border:solid; width:30%"><p>Logo image will be placed here but look  at this div behavious !!!!!!</p></div>
    <div style="border:solid; width:70%"><p>Site title will be placed here</p></div>
    <!-- -->
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Edite: here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cw9oycq7/

Comment: Your code is identical to the source html of the template. So it should work as intended if you're using correct resources. Can you make a demo fiddle so we can test it?

Comment: Please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/cw9oycq7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the BOOTSTRAP

Here's a working **[JSDIFFLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mbp7n9or/)**

```
  <div class="masthead">
    <!-- That's what I tried. Help me to find the good css style please -->
    <!-- ----------------CODE CHANGED HERE -------------- -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:solid;">
            <p>Logo image will be placed here but look  at this div behaviour !!!!!!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:solid">
            <p>Site title will be placed here</p>
        </div>
    <!-- -----------------CODE CHANGE END----------------- -->
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Downloads</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

You are trying to set width as 30% by `width` property. In bootstrap we use `COL-` attributes to set width/column size. For example -
`.col-md-4` // For medium screen
`.col-sm-6` // For small screen
`.col-lg-2` // For large screen

You can read more on how to use bootstrap grids [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Also, no need to use `pull-left` class when using `COL`. In most cases it is taken care of.

Comment: I voted for you answer. What can I do more ? Is there another way to mean my question is solved ?

Comment: Yes. To clear that the question is resolved, check the green 'tick' on the left hand side near the vote button. `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in`

Answer (score 1):

the enclosing container needs to have the row class so you can use this code

```
   <div class="masthead row">
    <!-- That's what I tried. Help me to find the good css style please -->
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="display:inline-block; border:solid; width:30%"><p>Logo image will be placed here but look  at this div behavious !!!!!!</p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="border:solid; width:70%"><p>Site title will be placed here</p></div>
    <!-- -->
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping. Sorry I tried to add row class but I'm not getting what I would like. Maybe your answer is good but I can't implement it. My problem is basic but my css skills are not great. Here is a jsFiddle. I just want my logo side by side with another div.

Comment: try the updated answer that I am pasting I have assumed that the Logo is the first div under masthead and the site title is the second div under masthead

Comment: You still have `width:30%` and `width:70%` properties which overrides `col-sm-6` class and hence it will not work.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda Thank you for helping sir PirateX solution was better.